# Reduce capacitor charging time

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

i am using flyback converter to charge a capatior 250uF 300V how can I reduce the charging time to 1 second OR how to increase current.   28V DC input voltage transformer output Voltage is 300V PWM frequency 55khz.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Bigger flyback converter.